# How to force close dark mode theme for Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I wrote some Jetpack Compose Demo, but I found library bug about adapt dark mode, therefore I want to show light mode only in my App, however when I set `<item name="android:forceDarkAllowed" tools:targetApi="q">false</item>` and `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` , those do not work, any idea for show light mode only for Jetpack Compose?

Comment: `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)` works fine to me, at least with my own activity(not sure about library).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The color we used for compose is not defined in xml, should be something like below:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposeTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colors = if (darkTheme) {
        DarkColorPalette
    } else {
        LightColorPalette
    }
    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colors,
        content = content
    )
}
```

As you can see, you can pass any color as you wish in MaterialTheme function call, just remove the dark mode check will do the trick.

Comment: I have tried this already, it do not work on my Xiaomi series phones, but it works fine when I use Pixel emulator. So it seems Jetpack Compose is still on early stage which means they still have a lot of room improve.

Comment: Do you mean even you hardcode the color in Xiaomi  it still transfer to dark mode?

Comment: If so I'm suspect it might be a global config not specify by single app.

Comment: Okay,  I tried another HUAWEI, that works. So far only XIAOMI got their config problem. I post this  [issue on github google jetpack sample](https://github.com/android/compose-samples/issues/706) hopefully this can be got attention for either google side and XIAOMI system department side.

Comment: Just to add to @Jintin answer, the composable theme function can be found under the ui/theme folder in the Theme.kt file.

Comment: Find any solution for this? @AndyZhang

Answer (score 1):

Simply add an item in both res/theme.xml and res/theme.xml(night) file is `<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>` in both darkand light mode it will be white.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

on theme.kt
change this

```
val colors = if (darkTheme) {
    DarkColorPalette
} else {
    LightColorPalette
}
```

to this

```
val colors = LightColorPalette
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).